# Change Google Maps start screen

Tags: google-maps

When I got my new phone, when I opened Google Maps, the default screen I had had a search bar at the top with a local map under and local stuff at the bottom. For some reason, when I open Maps, now it momentarily opens this screen and then jumps to "set destination" screen as though it assumes I want to navigate somewhere. I then have to press the back arrow to go to the search/local screen.

This has only recently changed but I can't find how to stop it so it opens on the normal search screen. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Were you, by any chance, opening the "Driving" widget instead of the "Maps" app?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I think you have just cracked this. The icon i was using is a square with a blue triangle and grey triangle (driving?). i have just found a maps icon with a coloured drop pin and that opens ok. I will see how it goes from here. Thanks again for your help